# PowerBI - Can I use a variable to query oracle multiple databases at once?

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I had multiple oracle connections as datasources quering the same data (diferent countrys).
What I have now is an append of all querys that the user can search in the report.
I have direct query mode, but as you know powerbi fecth all data on scheduled refresh.

What I have configured:
[image]

You can see all data input and the append "All Countrys"
All columns in every data source are the same.

What I want to know is if there is a way to only load the data (do the query) after the Search is done (Text Filter on visual), and bring that search input as a variable to put on all query's to have the append table results then.

Like:

= Oracle.Database("database/SID", [Query="select * from item_avail_sp where concat like '%searchinput%'"])

I tried to use parameters to relate the input search field but without success.
Also I try M code in advance editor (Text.combine) to generate the query but also can't relate the search field to a variable that i can use in m code.

If i manually put changes in query in advance editor it works for the related database.

Thank you guys!